# MVC 3 tries to launch URL to View instead of controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-routing

Sometimes when I launch my MVC 3 project it attempts to load the fully qualified URL for the view being rendered instead of the action within the controller (Which gives me a 404 error). Other times it works fine and actually hits the controller action like it's supposed to, but it's about 50/50.

The URL it hits sometimes is: `http://localhost:xxxx/Views/Account/LogOn.cshtml`

Here is the default route setup in the Global.asax file:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

I also tried removing the /{id} parameter from the route as I don't feel it's needed for the logon screen.

Any ideas? Currently the project is setup pretty simply with the default action method LogOn in the AccountController etc. The only thing I did was change the controller and action in the global.asax file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably using Visual Studio and you probably are actively editing a .cshtml page when you hit debug.

Try launching the debugger when you are either looking at a code file or a file from a project that isn't in the startup project (ie, your EF/model project) and see if that launches the debugger to the correct URL.

There might be a setting in the project properties that specifies the startup URL. I'll look for it and edit this post if I find it.

Comment: Thank you Joe for your reply. This was indeed what was happening. Launching the debugger while viewing the .cshtml page is a bad idea! I'm used to web forms and never ran into this! Thanks again, I will mark this as the answer when it allows.

Comment: Side note: Barry provided the project properties location below.

Answer (score 15):

Try this :go to `Project Properties` > `Web` > `Start Action`

And check the `Specific Page` option - leaving the text box blank.

Comment: Thank you Barry, this also helped out a lot. I never had to do that with web forms! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you using cassini (builtin dev web server in VS.Net)?  If so I get this all the time and seams to be a bug in VS.Net.  Switch to IIS 7.5 and you don't get it any more

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I am indeed using Cassini. I will give IIS 7.5 a try.