# ASP.NET MVC 5 DropDownListFor does not clear once provided value when empty model is passed later

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, html-select, default-value, html.dropdownlistfor

The problem:

**When there is a `DropDownListFor` on a page that uses a [default "select something" label](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownListFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable%7BSystem.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem%7D,System.String%29), then this label is only going to be used if a page with another value from the list has not yet been served by the server.

If it has, the "select something" label will not appear, and the previously served value will be pre-selected even when the current model's value is empty.**

I managed to reduce it to the following test case.

A standard MVC 5 project, with the standard nuget packages:

```xml
<package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
<package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

and nothing else (no javascript, no styles, no bundles).

TestModel:

```cs
public class TestModel
{
    private static readonly List<SelectListItem> m_PossiblePropertyValues = new List<SelectListItem>()
    { 
        // Explicitly specifying Value and Selected here just to be extra sure
        new SelectListItem(){ Text = "Option one", Value = "Option one", Selected = false },
        new SelectListItem(){ Text = "Option two", Value = "Option two", Selected = false }
    };
    

    public string PropertyThatComesFromDropdown { get; set; }
    
    public List<SelectListItem> PossiblePropertyValues
    {
        get { return m_PossiblePropertyValues; }
    }
}
```

HomeController:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        Models.TestModel model = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        {
            // Empty model, for the user to fill
            model = new Models.TestModel();
        }
        else
        {
            // Existing model, for the user to edit
            model = new Models.TestModel() { PropertyThatComesFromDropdown = "Option two" };
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Views/Home/Index.cshtml:

```
@model DropDownTestProject.Models.TestModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PropertyThatComesFromDropdown, Model.PossiblePropertyValues, "(select one)")

<h3>Debug values</h3>
<p>Is the model null? @(Model == null)</p>
<p>Is the property value null? @(Model == null ? "N/A" : (Model.PropertyThatComesFromDropdown == null).ToString())</p>
<p>Is the property valus empty? @(Model == null ? "N/A" : (Model.PropertyThatComesFromDropdown != null && Model.PropertyThatComesFromDropdown == string.Empty).ToString())</p>
<p>What is the property value? @(Model == null ? "N/A" : (Model.PropertyThatComesFromDropdown == null ? "<null>" : Model.PropertyThatComesFromDropdown == string.Empty ? "<empty>" : Model.PropertyThatComesFromDropdown))</p>
```

Now in the project properties set <kbd>Web</kbd> - <kbd>Start Action</kbd> to [use "Specific Page" and leave the field blank](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8851781/11683). The following then loads when you run the project:

> [image]

This is correct.

Now append `/index/any-value` to the URL, the following then loads:

> [image]

This is also correct.

Now delete the `/index/any-value` to navigate back to the very first page. The following loads:

> [image]

This is not correct.

Close the browser window, leaving the webserver running.
Open a different browser and navigate to the same address. Observe that the incorrect thing loads again even though that's a different browser.

It may be worth nothing that this does not appear to be a browser caching issue, because:

- Disabling caching with `OutputCache` on the controller's method does nothing, and
- the pre-selected value actually comes from the server in the HTML:

  > [image]

Now restart the web server and observe that the `(select one)` appears again... but only until you have navigated to a page with a value.

Adding `ModelState.Clear()` to the controller does not help.

What **does help** is setting the empty model's `PropertyThatComesFromDropdown` to `string.Empty` instead of leaving it `null`. Then it properly works across pages, but it does not feel like a proper solution.

**Is that expected behaviour and what is the correct way to stop it?**

Comment: Is any of this stored in session?  I know you showed a narrowed down test-case but because this is cross-browser that brings in another "mess".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Patrick This is ASP.NET MVC, not Webforms. Anyhow, no, I am not using `Session` or cookies. There are no cookies in the response either.

Comment: That's what I work with, ASP.Net MVC, including Core.  The server will cache certain things despite the browser, because it knows it's the same user.  I don't think your approach is unreasonable here.

Answer (score 0):

> What does help is setting the empty model's
>   PropertyThatComesFromDropdown to string.Empty instead of leaving it
>   null. Then it properly works across pages, but it does not feel like a
>   proper solution.

It very well might be, it would depend on the full code.

I wouldn't call that a hack, but since you are seeing this cross-browser, if that one-liner fixes it I'd call it a "proper" solution.

Comment: The full code is shown. The `model.PropertyThatComesFromDropdown = string.Empty` goes right after `model = new Models.TestModel();` in the controller, that is the only change. It does not feel right because a) models come from database where the values are properly `null`, and b) because upon submit the model binder will parse all empty strings to `null`s anyway.

Comment: Going to create a test project and see what I can do, give me a few :)